# D3 axis label rotate transition not smooth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transition

In my transition, an axis rotates 90 degree and then the labels rotate in the opposition direction in order to remain upright. Below is a minimal example of what I want, except the transition is not as smooth as it could be. If you watch closely, you can see the labels shift (translate) up before rotating into place.  How can I get rid of this shift? I've fiddled with `rotate` and `translate` to no avail.

(If you think this isn't too bad, I agree, but the shift is actually significantly more noticeable in my actual plot for some reason.)

**Update.** The culprit is the `text-anchor` property's getting switched back and forth between `middle` and `start`. Since these are discrete values, I can't think of a simple way to transition between them.

```js
var width = 170;
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 5])
  .range([0, width]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(scale)
  .ticks(6);

var graph = d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,10)');

graph.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + width + ')')
  .call(axis);

var tickLabels = d3.selectAll('text');

var toggle = false;
d3.select('button').on('click', function() {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if (toggle) {
    graph.transition().duration(1000)
      // .attr('transform','rotate(-90)');
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90 ' + (width / 2 + 10) + ' ' + (width / 2 + 10) + ')');
    tickLabels.transition().duration(1500).delay(1000)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
      .style("text-anchor", "start");
  } else {
    graph.transition().duration(1000)
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(0) translate(10,10)');
    tickLabels.transition().duration(1500).delay(1000)
      .attr('y', 9)
      .attr('x', 0.5)
      .attr('dy', '0.71em')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(0)')
      .style('text-anchor', null);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width='200' height='200'>
</svg>
<div>
  <button>Rotate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, which is actually fairly simple. The key is to alter the `x` attribute to offset the `text-anchor` shift before rotating the labels. The result is actually quite nice.

```js
var width = 170;
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 5])
  .range([0, width]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(scale)
  .ticks(6);

var graph = d3.select('svg').append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(10,10)');

graph.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + width + ')')
  .call(axis);

var tickLabels = d3.selectAll('text');

var toggle = false;
d3.select('button').on('click', function() {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if (toggle) {
    graph.transition().duration(1000)
      // .attr('transform','rotate(-90)');
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90 ' + (width / 2 + 10) + ' ' + (width / 2 + 10) + ')');
    tickLabels.transition().duration(0).delay(1000)
      .attr('x', -3)
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(90)");
  } else {
    graph.transition().duration(1000)
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(0) translate(10,10)');
    tickLabels.transition().duration(0).delay(1000)
      .attr('x', 12)
      .style('text-anchor', null)
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr('y', 9)
      .attr('x', 0.5)
      .attr('dy', '0.71em')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(0)');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width='200' height='200'>
</svg>
<div>
  <button>Rotate</button>
</div>
```